# SQL Server 2012 query won't save as view

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

I've got the following fully-working query in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT
    iif(((DATEPART(dw, MeasurementTime) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) < 2,'Weekend','Weekday') AS PartOfWeek,
    Seasons.Label AS Season,
    CONVERT(TIME,MeasurementTime) AS TimeOfDay,
    FeederLoads.FeederNo AS FeederNo,
    Avg(FeederLoads.kVA) AS Mean,
    StDev(FeederLoads.kVA) AS StdDev
FROM
    FeederLoads INNER JOIN
    Seasons
    ON  Month(FeederLoads.MeasurementTime) = Seasons.Month1 OR 
        Month(FeederLoads.MeasurementTime) = Seasons.Month2 OR 
        Month(FeederLoads.MeasurementTime) = Seasons.Month3
GROUP BY
    ((DATEPART(dw, MeasurementTime) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7),
    Seasons.Label,
    CONVERT(TIME,MeasurementTime),
    FeederLoads.FeederNo;
```

When I copy and paste the query into the SQL pane of the view definition window, however, the view fails to save.

The error message I get is:

> Error in list of function arguments: '<' not recognized. Unable to
>   parse query text.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be running that code in a query designer. Unfortunately, not all designers are created equal - so just take the code and run it in a SQL Server Management Studio query window.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59d86/1/0

This is no different from some very complex MS Access queries that has to be created in SQL View.

Comment: Yep, this is correct - to clarify, using the above query for a view in the SSMS view definition window did not work, using @Richardakacyberkiwi's query in a standard query designer window works fine.